# Convert Security xml into code

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a xml code like follows

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationProcessingFilter" />
        <custom-filter before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="socialAuthenticationFilter"  />
        <intercept-url pattern="/blah/404-error" access="permitAll()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/blah/500-error" access="permitAll()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="blah" />
        <logout logout-url="/blah/logout" logout-success-url="/blah/signin" />
    </http>



<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="in.security.ReCaptchaAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/blah/authentication" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
        <beans:property name="privateKey" value="key" />
    </beans:bean>
```

I am not sure how i can configure the above xml configuration using spring code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

I can normally see that the examples code contains the following

```
auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
```

or

```
auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .withDefaultSchema()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
```

But i am not using either inmemory authentication as well as jdbc authentication. But i am not using any of this authentication. I am using filters....
I am not sure what to put inside the `configureGlobal` method.

Comment: Can you post the `authenticationProcessingFilter` definition, as well?

Comment: updated the filter defination